# C++ Passing Polymorphic Pointer of Pointers to Function

Tags: function, pointers, multidimensional-array

In trying to shorted my code for readability, I wound up changing too much and making mistakes. This is still condensed but taken straight from my code.

My problem is that I have a class called "function" and a derived class "pwfunction" which both have the virtual () operator. I'd like to pass an array of pointers to my "function" objects to various actual functions and use the () operator.

Final edit: This is a SSCCE version of what I'm talking about.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class function
{
public:
    virtual double operator () (double x) {return 1.5;}
};

class pwfunction : public function
{
public:
    virtual double operator() (double x) {return 2.0;}
};

void interface();
void definefuncs (function** funcs, long unsigned numfuncs);
void interpolate(function* infunc);
void solvefuncs(function** funcs, long unsigned numfuncs);

int main()
{
    interface();
    return 0;
}

void interface()
{
    long unsigned numfuncs = 1;
    function* funcs[numfuncs];

    definefuncs(funcs, numfuncs);

    solvefuncs(funcs, numfuncs);
}

void definefuncs (function** funcs, long unsigned numfuncs)
{
    interpolate(funcs[0]);
}

void interpolate(function* infunc)
{
    infunc = new pwfunction();
    cout<< (*infunc)(1.5)<<endl;    //works
}

void solvefuncs(function** funcs, long unsigned numfuncs)
{
    cout<< (*funcs[0])(1.5);    //Error Message: Segmentation fault
}
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/iYbOyN). No complaints from valgrind either. If you made one mistake copying your code, could it be you made another one as well? Make sure to paste a SSCCE here, and make sure that the code you paste does indeed exhibit the behaviour you claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the following:

```
void interpolate(function* infunc)
{
    infunc = new pwfunction();
    cout<< (*infunc)(1.5)<<endl;    //works
}
```

is probably not doing what you want. infunc is allocated locally, and this does not affect anything else outside or this function (and is btw a memory leak). Interpolate should either return infunc, or allocate the original variable, such as

```
void interpolate(function*& infunc) ...
```

Comment: Ya, the memory leak will be taken care of momentarily when I implement a proper container for my objects. This program is designed to interpolate a list of data into various mathematical functions and perform some numerical analysis on it. But you're saying that even though I'm passing this as a pointer, it making a copy of the pointer infunc, assigning the copy to the new pwfunction but not the original pointer infunc?

Comment: What I meant is that `infunc = new pwfunction();` actually assigns the function you're allocating, to a copy of the variable passed to interpolate(). So 2 consequences: the original variable is still unchanged (not initialized) causing your crash, and the memory leak.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks! I didn't know you could pass a pointer by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate array for the `funclist` data in `somefunction`, so anything can happen. Perhaps you mean

```
func* funclist[1];
```

to indicate a one-element array of `func` pointers.

Comment: Ya, that was a typo. I still have the problem though.